ASP.NET Core MVC : asp-action tag helper adds asp-route-id without asking?
In ASP.NET Core MVC, I have a route configured like this:
app.MapControllerRoute(
  name: "default",
  pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

In Controllers/HomeController.cs I have
public IActionResult MyAction()
{
    return View();
}

In Views/Home/MyAction.cshtml I have
<a asp-action="MyAction">My action</a>

With a GET request to Home/MyAction, this link gets rendered as:
<a href="/Home/MyAction">My action</a>

as expected.
With a GET request to Home/MyAction/1, this link gets rendered as:
<a href="/Home/MyAction/1">My action</a>

I was expecting this link to be rendered as:
<a href="/Home/MyAction">My action</a>

so without the id since I didn't add asp-route-id="1".
Why is the id included? Is this a bug or a feature? I can't find a description of this behavior in the docs.

Hi @Tom, This behavior is actually by design in ASP.NET Core. When the route includes an optional parameter (like id? in {controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}), ASP.NET Core will use any route values present in the current request's context to construct links, even if those values aren't specified in the link.

Hi @Rena, This only seems to happen when the action (<a asp-action=MyAction">My action</a>) corresponds to the path from the GET request (Home/MyAction/1). For example this doesn't happen for a link like <a asp-action="MyOtherAction>My other action</a> in Views/Home/MyAction.cshtml when the GET request stays the same.

Hi @Tom, Yes. Of course it only work for the same request. If you want to render the link without id, you can override the default behavior by explicitly setting asp-route-id="" in the link:<a asp-action="MyAction" asp-route-id="">My action</a>.
